# Refresh Angular 4 Component

Tags: json, angular, typescript, refresh, reload

I've seen that this question already has been asked sometimes here on stackoverflow, but none of them seems to match my example.

I have two different json files. In my sidemenu, I have two buttons. By clicking on one of them, I want to display the data of the other json file I got. So in my view then, the data of the other file should be shown. I think I got it halfway, because when I click on the buttons, I can see in my console, that the other json file is loaded.

I'm switching and changing the files like this:

**rest.ts**

```
jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json'; // --> this file should be loaded at first (default file)
.
.
.
 // the buttons call this function
changeColorJson(name) {
    if(name === 'S'){
      this.jsonFile = 'secondarycolors.json';
      this.getDataFromJson(); // here I'm loading the function below. In my console then I can see, that this file was correctly loaded
    }
    else {
      this.jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json';
      this.getDataFromJson(); // same here
    }
}


getDataFromJson() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('../../assets/data/' + this.jsonFile) //here should be the path with the correct file
        .subscribe((data) => {  
  resolve(data);
          console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I called the function getDataFromJson() in changeColorJson(name). I have a console log to show which json file is loaded and this works fine.

**Now to my problem:**

I'm calling getJsonDataFromJson() from the changeColorJson(name) function, where it loads the correct json file when I click on one of the buttons, but I am also calling getJsonDataFromJson() from the component I want to display the files in and there I'm calling the function only once, and then it doesn't get the new data. Now I'm asking, what can I do to refresh my color component? So it also gets the new data?

Here's my colors component:

**colors.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colors">
  <p>{{color.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**colors.ts**

```
colors: any;
.
.
.
  getData() {
    this.restProvider.getDataFromJson() //the same function from above
      .then(data => {
        this.colors = data; //adding the data I got from json to colors

   // What can I do here to refresh the data I'm getting?
   });
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't make a new instance of the service. If you do then each time the getData function is called you will get the default value as the changeColorJson triggered from the buttons belongs to another instance.. Use Augury to check your injections. The best way to do this would be to use observables/subject in order to trigger the changes in your components when the value changes. Do your research https://toddmotto.com/component-architecture-reactive-forms-angular
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

You can use observables in order to detect the changes everywhere.

```
jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json'; // --> this file should be loaded at first (default file)
myData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
.
.
.
 // the buttons call this function
changeColorJson(name) {
    if(name === 'S'){
      this.jsonFile = 'secondarycolors.json';
      this.getDataFromJson(); // here I'm loading the function below. In my console then I can see, that this file was correctly loaded
    }
    else {
      this.jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json';
      this.getDataFromJson(); // same here
    }
}


getDataFromJson() {
    this.http.get('../../assets/data/' + this.jsonFile) //here should be the path with the correct file
        .subscribe((data) => {  
       this.myData.next(data)
    });

  }
```

and you need to subscribe to this variable

```
colors: any;
.
.
.
  getData() {
    this.restProvider.getDataFromJson() //the same function from above
    this.restProvider.myData.subscribe(data => {
      this.colors = data
    }
  }
```